# make regex more specific in getting consequtive digits

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, pandas, text

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'Data':['123456A122 119999 This 1234522261 1A1619 BL171111 A-1-24',
                                  '134456 dont 12-23-34-45-5-6 Z112 NOT 01-22-2001',
                                  'mix: 1A25629Q88 or A13B ok'], 
                          'IDs': ['A11','B22','C33'],
                          })
```

I have the following `df` as seen above. I am using the following to get only consequtive digits

```
reg = r'((?:[\d]-?){6,})'
df['new'] = df['Data'].str.findall(reg) 

    Data    IDs new
0               [123456,119999, 1234522261, 171111]
1               [134456, 12-23-34-45-5-6, 01-22-2001]
2               []
```

This picks up many things I dont want like `171111` from `BL171111` and `123456` from `123456A122` etc

I would like the following output which only picks up 6 consequtive digits

```
    Data    IDs new
0               [119999]
1               [134456]
2               []
```

How do I change my regex to so?

```
reg = r'((?:[\d]-?){6,})'
```

Comment: `df.Data.str.split(expand=True).apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').bfill(1).iloc[:,0]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regex to use word boundaries (`\b`) and limit the number of digits to exactly 6, like this:

```
reg = r'(\b\d{6}\b)'
```

This looks for a word boundary, 6 numbers, and another word boundary.

Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kw5He3/1).